# How to restore a broken property inheritance in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, inheritance, data-binding, custom-controls

Is there a way to re-enable property inheritance in xaml when is broken?

Here is the CustomControl:

```
public class CustomControl : DataGrid
{
    static CustomControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl)));
    }

    public object Item
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(ItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Item", typeof(object), typeof(CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public object ContentControl
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(ContentControlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentControlProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentControlProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ContentControl", typeof(object), typeof(CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(OnContentChanged));

    private static void OnContentChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = d as CustomControl;

        if (e.OldValue != null)
        {
            control.RemoveLogicalChild(e.OldValue);
        }

        control.AddLogicalChild(e.NewValue);
    }
}
```

The xaml part. (Generic.xaml)

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl}">
                <ContentPresenter DataContext="{TemplateBinding Item}" ContentSource="ContentControl"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And this is the MainWindow:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Skip this tab...">
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Here...">
        <WpfApplication:CustomControl DataContext="{Binding}" x:Name="CustomControl" Item="{Binding InnerViewModel}">
            <WpfApplication:CustomControl.ContentControl>
                <!-- The DataContext is not inherited... -->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding InnerName}" />
            </WpfApplication:CustomControl.ContentControl>
        </WpfApplication:CustomControl>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Finally, the corresponding ViewModels:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public InnerViewModel InnerViewModel { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        InnerViewModel = new InnerViewModel();
        Name = "ViewModel";
    }
}

public class InnerViewModel
{
    public string InnerName { get; set; }

    public InnerViewModel()
    {
        InnerName = "InnerViewModel";
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is no broken dependency property value inheritance in your example but rather you totally kill DataContext.

Remove this `DataContext = "{Binding}"`

The DataContext is already there. You are extra Binding DataContext to itself again. That ruins things.

However if by removing `DataContext = "{Binding}"` you still cannot provide data to ContentControl try set the ContentPropertyAtttribute.

To read more about this attribute please check this link out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you, but I made this example only with 1 content dp for simplicity, so to make long story short, I have multiple dependecy properties which contains content - one for Add datagrid content, one for edit and one for delete. In this case there is no way to put multiple [ContentProperty] attributes.

Comment: Oh ok, well in such case you can leave ContentPropertyAttribute away and also remove binding to DataContext and you should do fine.

Comment: The DataContext is not the "Item" which is InnerViewModel. If you look closely in Generic.xaml you will see "<ContentPresenter DataContext="{TemplateBinding Item}" ContentSource="ContentControl"/>". An the part with DataContext="{TemplateBinding Item}" is not working and it will work if I comment out control.AddLogicalChild(e.NewValue); but this will broke my ability to use Element Name Binding.

Comment: I ll run your source code later and I ll let you know about my progress.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, a dirty solution occurred to my mind. I do not think that this is right way but you can set the DataContext manually.

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Item", typeof(object), typeof(CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(OnItemPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnItemPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = d as CustomControl;
        var frameworkElement = control.ContentControl as FrameworkElement;
        if (frameworkElement != null)
        {
            frameworkElement.DataContext = control.Item;
        }
    }
```